# Moodle Student Login Quiz administration Logs

Tags: moodle

I am new to moodle I have created a quiz in moodle. For student login, in the Quiz Administration there is "Logs" available. In these logs, the student can view logs for all participants and all activities.

Is there any way i can set it so that only the currently logged in student logs are available.

Please help.

Moodle verson 2.8.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, student role does not have permission for view course logs. But is was enabled in my moodle by another team member.  I turned off permission to for student to view course logs. So, Quiz administration logs is now not available for Student. If needed it can be turned on and customized for student role.